# MessageBox

Tags: c#, messagebox, icon

```
const string message = "1111.\n11111\nВ111\nС1111\n1111";
var result = MessageBox.Show(message, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

---

И выдает вот это:

**Ошибка 1:** Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string, string)" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов C:\Users\Антон\Desktop\Form1.cs 49 26 WindowsFormsApplication1

**Ошибка 2:**   Аргумент "2": преобразование типа из "System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon" в "string" невозможно    C:\Users\Антон\Desktop\Form1.cs 50  38  WindowsFormsApplication1

---

В С# новичок. Кто подскажет в чем трабла? Вообще, мне нужно, что по нажатию кнопочки "info" вылезало окошко с обычной иконкой и текстом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет такого перегруженного метода. Посмотри [вот этот](http://msdn.microsoft.com/RU-RU/library/365dky5y.aspx)

```
MessageBox.Show("XXX", "YYY",MessageBoxButtons.OK,  MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: Благодарю!